# plotting summation to check for convergence

Tags: plotting, series-expansion, summation

Our assignment was to enter in a series and check to see if it converges by graphing.

However, when I attempt to graph it, I get a bunch of errors that I'm not sure what they mean. Best way to show it is a picture [image]

I'm not 100% sure that the "Sum does not converge" is accurate, because I dont think it would be assigned if it didn't. so maybe I entered in the series wrong?
can anyone offer some enlightenment here?

Comment: is n the number of terms in the sum? it should appear on the right hand side of s[n_]

Comment: Please include correctly formatted, copy-and-pastable code in your post, not screenshots; possible answerers don't like to use their valuable (literally-)free time re-writing code into *Mathematica* and running it. You can edit your post by clicking the grey button at the bottom of your post, and you can click the grey question mark at the right of the toolbar for formatting help. That said, you probably want to replace the `Infinity` with `n` on the right-hand side of the `s[n_]` definition. The infinite sum doesn't converge, so you have to do a finite sum, as it seems you are attempting.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The series does not converge. The terms (1/cube root(k)) are larger than the harmonic series (Sum of 1/k) which does not converge. No need for a computer program.

Comment: @user48709 I moved your answer to comment, you couldn't due to reputation restrictions. The question was to "check to see if it converges by graphing", so while your comment is on topic, it does not provide the answer the this specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Accumulate[Table[1/CubeRoot[n], {n, 1, 5000}]]]
```

strongly suggests this does not converge.